# IBM AIX aix how to start cluster when a lv is modified and other cluster nodes are down?

Tags: aix, cluster

I am using  an AIX HACMP cluster . By mistake a logical volume in a shared vg is resized.

Now when using smitty clstart I am unable to start the cluster. 
Only this node in the cluster is  up.

While starting  the cluster is asking whether to re-import the shared vg 
( since time stamp file in shared vg is inconsistent ) .

How to resolve this mistake ?

Comment: good luck with this one, AIX question are usually the less answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you would actually read again what you've written and what `smitty clstart` dialog is telling, you have more then 50% to solve this.

> While starting the cluster is asking whether to re-import the shared
>   vg ( since time stamp file in shared vg is inconsistent ).

As you changed a logical volume outside of the cluster, the VGDA data cached by the cluster does not match the actual data on disk and it needs to re-sync those. In `smitty clstart` you should change `Automatically correct errors found during verification?` to interactive, and it will propose to correct that error. Then sync the cluster definition to the other nodes.